# Binding to ng2-select active value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I'm using [ng2-select](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select) dropdown menu library. I want to be able to bind to the selected data and set it as the 'active' value later on.

For example, say I have a model object called `Car`.

```
export class Car { 
  public id: number;
}
```

Then in my template, say I have something like this:

```
<ng-select [multiple]="false" [active]="myCar.id" (selected)="myCar.id = $event" [items]="[{id: '1', text: 'Car 1'}, {id: '2', text: 'Car 2'}]"></ng-select>
```

This causes an infinite loop in the change detection cycle.. I'm not sure how to solve this. The ultimate goal is to basically 'remember' what the user selects, then serialize it to a JSON, and then when I pass the stored value back later, the dropdown menu would then automatically select that value...

Comment: you get the infinite loop after you select a value?

Answer (score 1):

Before all, fix this problems in your code:

- **selected** return an object {id: ..., text: ...}
- **active** want an array of object [{id: ..., text: ...}]
- your car **type** has id in **number** type but you have items with id in string type

Try this out:

```html
<ng-select [multiple]="false" [active]="[myCar]" (selected)="myCar = $event" [items]="[{id: 1, text: 'Car 1'}, {id: 2, text: 'Car 2'}]"></ng-select>
```

The full API can be found here : https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/